# Effects of number of classes on inference time in Object Detection Api

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am Using tensorflow Object detection api, where i used Fasterrcnn_resnet50 network. I trained it on 5 classes. Now I want to train it on 200 classes. My question here is, whether increasing number of classes will have an effect on my inference speed.

Answer (score 1):

No, the number of classes should not have a significant effect on inference speed.

Changing how many classes to detect will only change a few layers at the end, the vast majority of the model will be identical in size (and therefore require the same amount of computations).